# ¿Como puedo poner en mayusculas letras en medio de una cadena en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo cadenas de string en minúsculas separadas por espacios y quiero que la primera letra de la cadena más cada letra que venga después de un espacio quede en mayúscula al hacer el select.

Ejemplo:
tengo la cadena 'puerto rico' en un campo, y al momento de hacer el select quiero que se muestre así: *Puerto Rico*

Estoy ocupando la version **8.0.30**

Comment: que as intentado hasta ahora? que as investigado? anade el codigo de los que as logrado de momento!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como tal, en MySQL no existe una manera - como en Oracle, por ejemplo - en el que se puede colocar la primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula, sin embargo, en internet puedes encontrar un sin fin de funciones que replican el funcionamiento del `INITCAP` de Oracle (básicamente es la función que hace lo que estás buscando, pero en este DBMS).

Una de las funciones que encontré es la siguiente:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION initcap(cadena VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS VARCHAR(100) deterministic
BEGIN 
DECLARE pos INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE tmp VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT ''; 
DECLARE result VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT ''; 
REPEAT SET pos = LOCATE(' ', cadena); 
 IF pos = 0 THEN SET pos = CHAR_LENGTH(cadena); 
 END IF; 
 SET tmp = LEFT(cadena,pos); 
 SET result = CONCAT(result, UPPER(LEFT(tmp,1)),SUBSTR(tmp,2)); 
 SET cadena = RIGHT(cadena,CHAR_LENGTH(cadena)-pos); 
UNTIL CHAR_LENGTH(cadena) = 0 END REPEAT; 
RETURN result; 
END;
```

Se comprueba de la siguiente forma:

```sql
select initcap('puerto rico') conInitCap
-- output: 'Puerto Rico'
```

Te dejo dos links:

- <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/41aOJBlf)</kbd> con la función corriendo.
- <kbd>[**FUENTE**](https://cambrico.net/09-07-2008/como-poner-la-primera-letra-de-una-frase-en-mayusculas-con-mysql)</kbd> donde extraje la función.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si bien esa función que colocaste no me funcionó, me sirvió como punto de partida para encontrar lo que necesitaba hacer

Comment: Sería interesante que publicaras la que sí te funciono como una respuesta para poder compararlas.